# How to identify coordinates in R

Tags: r

I would like to identify which coordinate of my vector gives me the greatest value. For a simple example suppose that:

```
x <- c(10,22,20,18,5)
```

The greatest value is 22, but how can i automatically identify that the coordinate 2 has the greatest value?

Thanks!

Comment: `which.max(x)`.

Answer (score 4):

`which.max` is your friend as pointed out by @Hong Ooi

```
> x <- c(10,22,20,18,5)
> which.max(x)
[1] 2
```

Another (not optimal way) is a combination of `which` and `max`.

```
> which(x==max(x))
[1] 2
```

Comment: It'll be helpful to note which(x == max(x), arr.ind=TRUE) when x is not one-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

First, find the greatest value with max:

```
> max(x)
[1] 22
```

From there, you can figure out which value(s) in the vector match the greatest value:

```
> x==max(x)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

which() can be used to translate the boolean vector into indices:

```
which(x==max(x))
[1] 2
```

Comment: +1 I don't see why this needed downvoting. This is how anyone who does not know which.max or working in any other language or using a multi-deimensional array will do this.

Comment: @asb I agree, a nice answer.

Comment: @asb Really? In any other language you would iterate over the length of the vector twice and create an intermediate boolean vector?

Comment: Hmm.. I wasn't expecting this. Let me qualify: In any other high-level language where there isn't a need for premature optimization, this will be the first approach. In a low level language I'll probably loop over once and use an extra `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you say co-ordinates, I am assuming the case-in-point may not always be a one-dimensional vector and therefore I am going to make my comment to @Jilber an answer.

A general answer is to use `which(x == max(x), ind.arr = TRUE)`. This will give you all dimensions of an array of any dimensionality. For e.g.

```
R> x <- array(runif(8), dim=rep_len(2, 3))                                                                                                                              
R> x
, , 1

          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.3202624 0.7740697
[2,] 0.9374742 0.2370483

, , 2

          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.9423731 0.2099402
[2,] 0.7035772 0.8195685

R> which(x == max(x), arr.ind=TRUE)
     dim1 dim2 dim3
[1,]    1    1    2

R> which(x[1, , ] == max(x[1, , ]), arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   2

R> which(x[1, 1, ] == max(x[1, 1, ]), arr.ind=TRUE)
[1] 2
```

For the specific case of one-dimensional vectors, `which.max` is a 'faster' solution.